# TeamCity - NamedParameterNotFound for Get-ChildItem on TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Horrendous day with TeamCity and PowerShell ends with

```
NamedParameterNotFound
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolderPath -Filter $CodeFilename -File -Recurse
```

The offending line (above, bottom) is in a PS1 being ran by TeamCity.

The script runs beautifully on my local dev machine and the PS version on TC server is 4.0 apparently, and I can see the `-File` param in a PS command window on the TC server itself.

How on Earth can the `-File` parameter be missing from `Get-ChildItem`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Script arguments" box in TeamCity, I

changed this

```
-RootFolderPath '%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%' -VersionString '%AssemblyVersionStringWithCounter%'
```

to this

```
-RootFolderPath %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% -VersionString %AssemblyVersionStringWithCounter%
```

And it works. Lord knows.

Comment: Are you sure you can reproduce it by simply removing the quotes again? Or just unquoting one of the quoted values? Does either of them contain spaces?